# Ionic 2 with Stripe Integration

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, stripe-payments, ionic2

I'm kind of new to Ionic as a whole and I'm using Ionic 2 right now. I did:

```
npm install stripe
```

and I got the stripe module into node_modules folder. This is my code in my payments page to access Stripe:

```
'use strict';
declare var require: any;
var Stripe = require('stripe')('API_KEY');
```

and when I call a function such as:

```
Stripe.tokens.create({
  card: {
    "number": '4242424242424242',
    "exp_month": 12,
    "exp_year": 2017,
    "cvc": '123'
  }
}, function(err, token) {
  // asynchronously called
  console.log("error: " + err);
  console.log("token: " + token);
});
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: exec is not a function
```

exec is in stripe.js in this line:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
```

I don't know how to fix it, anyone have any pointers or maybe a different (correct) way of integrating Stripe with Ionic 2? Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

First, you'll need to distinguish between the client side (the ionic app) and the server side (where payments are processed and the card validated).

For instance, [this template contains the full source code for Ionic2 with Stripe](https://www.noodl.io/market/product/P201702241736843/stripe-with-ionic2-quickly-and-easily-integrate-stripe-in-your-ionic2-app).

As I read from the docs, you only need to make HTTP **post** calls in your Ionic app to the server.

You can either send it to an already hosted server (such as [Stripe Payments Kit / NoodlioPay](https://noodliopay.com)) that integrates Stripe or setup your own (as you try to do). View the docs of the [link](https://www.noodl.io/market/product/P201702241736843/stripe-with-ionic2-quickly-and-easily-integrate-stripe-in-your-ionic2-app) I sent to see how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an Ionic expert by any means, but my guess is that you're trying to use Stripe.js [1] (a client-side library) to execute a server-side request.  If you're tokenizing, you should try and either follow the instructions outlined in the Stripe.js documentation or completely remove Stripe.js and implement your code using just the Node.js [2] bindings.

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js

[2] https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node